# Graphviz (Java) label of rectangle-node writes over the ends of the node

Tags: java, graphviz, dot, image-graphviz

My problem is that long node labels do reach on both sides over the end of the node

[image: see here]

This only occurs with node-shapes like `rectangle`, `square`, `tab` or similar but never with `oval`,`circle` or `diamond`.
I am using the Java Graphviz-Engine (guru-nidi:graphviz-java:0.14.1) and my corresponding code (simplified) is the following:

String graphString =

```java
digraph g { 
extralargesubject [shape=diamond]; 
extralargeobject [shape=rectangle] ; 
extralargesubject -> extralargeobject; 
}
```

and

```java
import guru.nidi.graphviz.engine.Format;
import guru.nidi.graphviz.engine.Graphviz;
import guru.nidi.graphviz.model.MutableGraph;
import guru.nidi.graphviz.parse.Parser;

MutableGraph g = new Parser().read(graphString);
BufferedImage image = Graphviz.fromGraph(g).render(Format.SVG).toImage();
```

Maybe someone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I only worked with the .jar. But that's only the Engine. Of course I had to install Graphviz also on my machine. Now I did and everything works now fine!